# How to Inset many parameters into on case statement using || operation

Tags: c#, asp.net

Into below case statement i am trying to minimize the code to make the application faster little bit, so i tried to combine all categories which will show the same panel (generlpanel) into one case part but it didnt works, while if i choose Accounting then the (generlpanel) will appear normally as well as Audio the (panelforall) will appear. So can some one help me to fix it.

```
if (Request.QueryString["cat"] != null)
        {
            string cat = Request.QueryString["cat"].ToString();
            string category = string.Empty;
            switch (cat)
            {
                case "Animal Accessories || Animal care || Birds || Others animals || Cats || Cows || Dogs || Fish || Horses":
                    category = "Animal Accessories || Animal care || Birds || Others animals || Cats || Cows || Dogs || Fish || Horses";
                    generlpanel.Visible = true;
                    break;

                case "Accounting":
                    category = "Accounting";
                    generlpanel.Visible = true;
                    break;

                 case "Audio":
                    category = "Audio";
                    panelforall.Visible = true;
                    break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would write your switch like this.

```
    Case "Animal Accessories": Case" Animal care": Case "Birds":


                     generlpanel.Visible = true;
                     break;

   case "Accounting":
                    category = "Accounting";
                    generlpanel.Visible = true;
                    break;

   case "Audio":
                    category = "Audio";
                    panelforall.Visible = true;
                    break;
```

Take a look at some of these examples. [switch (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/06tc147t.aspx)

Comment: But in this case i will have many many of lines and that's what i don't want to make the page faster, is there is any another way for example using other kind of statments to do what i am looking for?!

Comment: The resources needed to read multiple lines is negligible. It costing literally nothing, apart from obviously screen real-estate. Check out@Frode F's solution if it must be on one line.

Comment: @Simon, Look at my recent edit. You could put them all on one line. Else, use an if statement instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple conditions in a case. You could write multiple case-statements like @DanCundy answered, or you could use `if` and regex. Ex.

```
if (Regex.Match(cat, "Animal Accessories|Animal care|Birds|Ohers animals|Cats|Cows|Dogs|Fish|Horses", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success)
{
    category = cat;
    generlpanel.Visible = true;

}
else if (cat.ToUpperInvariant() == "Accounting".ToUpperInvariant())
{
    category = "Accounting";
    generlpanel.Visible = true;

}
else if (cat.ToUpperInvariant() == "Audio".ToUpperInvariant())
{
    category = "Audio";
    panelforall.Visible = true;

}
```